# running bash script from within octave / matlab getting error executing bash syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, matlab, shell, octave

I get the *error executing bash syntax error near unexpected token `('*

I know the error is caused by the **')'** but I thought placing the commands in-between **' '** is suppose to allow the parenthesis in a directory name.  How can I fix this without renaming the name?

The matlab / octave code is:

```
syscmd=strcat({'bash -c '},{''''},{'cd '},dirpathpls,newdirname,{' && exec bash xfade.sh'},{''''}) %used to run script to join files in stretch directory
system(syscmd);
```

and it produces what is below:

```
bash -c 'cd /tmp/h1/clients/04212015142432811_Fs_1000_ahh/pls/03sox_a_Fs_1000_ahh_(000_bit)_(0.0000
0sig_in_deg)_to_(508_bit)_(30.00000sig_in_deg) && exec bash xfade.sh'
```

please note:
It's being called from inside octave 3.8.1 a math program like matlab

Comment: Much better. If you'd included that inside the question the first time...

Comment: ...that said, the only answer you have so far has substantial security risks. Be careful of using it if the directory names contain any user-provided data.

Comment: Also -- my answer about getting rid of the `bash -c`? It still applies here. A `system("foo")` call invokes `sh -c 'foo'`; since there's no bash-specific syntax, that `sh` shell is good enough for your use case, and you have no reason whatsoever to complicate your quoting/escaping by invoking an inner `bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `'` within a bash command line does allow the use of reserved characters like `(` without escaping; however, that is not what you are doing. Everything within your `'`s is being passed to bash for interpretation, bash isn't interpreting the `'`s as part of the command. Something like this should work:

```
syscmd=strcat({'bash -c '},{''''},{'cd "'},dirpathpls,newdirname,{'" && exec bash xfade.sh'},{''''}) %used to run script to join files in stretch directory
system(syscmd);
```

I don't know matlab/octave, but I hope that conveys the idea. The `"` should effectively escape the parens. The only pitfall there is if your directory name might have a `$` or `"` in it, in that case, or you have `'` AND `"` in your dir name, things are going to get silly.

Comment: This is quite risky if either parameter used can contain user-provided data. It would be considerably safer to use `'` for the inner quotes, and escape any instances of them found within the data -- for instance, by replacing `'` with `'"'"'` in `dirpathpls` or `newdirname`.

Comment: That said, there's no reason at all to use `bash -c` inside a `system()` call -- a `system()` call is implicitly in the context of `sh -c`, so the `bash -c` is nothing but redundant inefficiency.

Answer (score 0):

As I told you in your other question on this topic: Don't use `bash -c`; it's not necessary for octave to run an external command, and you're doing nothing but making your life harder by trying.

```
command=strcat({'cd '''},
           strrep(strcat(dirpathpls,newdirname),
                  '''',
                  '''"''"'''''),
           {''' && exec bash xfade.sh'})
system(syscmd);
```

Two key differences:

- We're using the `sh -c` implicitly created by the system() call
- We're escaping the filenames, preventing any malicious content within them from escaping the quotes and being executed.

---

How that escaping works:

Single-quoted strings in POSIX shells are ended only by a following single-quote. To insert a literal single quote into them, one needs to end the single-quoted string and then enter a different quoting type. Thus:

```
'"'"'
```

...in which the first `'` ends the prior quoting type; the `"` enters a double-quoted context (in which a single-quote literal can be recognized; the `'` after it is then your literal single-quote character; the `"` following ends the double-quoted context, and the final `'` resumes a single-quoted context.

This is all made more complicated by doubling the `'`s to `''`s for Octave's syntax; this is how one gets

```
strrep(content, '''', '''"''"''''')
```

...to replace all `'`s with `'"'"'`s.